# My select statment using pdo is not returning any rows

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Im trying to do an update news system, and so I need first to get the id of news that I want to update.

Im passing a variable "edit" when I click in each news to edit, like:

```
href="panel.php?nav=categories/categories-edit&edit='.$result['id_cat'].'"
```

And then I have my select, but its not working, when I print number of rows of my select statment, Im always getting always '0' rows.

```
$urledit = $_GET['edit'];
$read= $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from categories WHERE id = ?");  
$read->bindParam(1, $urledit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$read->execute();
$result = $read->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $urledit; //show me 101 that is id Im passing in url
print_r($read->rowCount()); //show me 0
```

Comment: Try escaping reserved word `id` with backticks `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$read->rowCount()` return the number of affected rows from last `INSERT`/`DELETE`/`UPDATE` statement. You need to execute COUNT query. More details in the PHP manual entry for [`rowCout()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

> **PDOStatement::rowCount()** returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the
>   corresponding PDOStatement object.
>
> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was
>   a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows
>   returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed
>   for all databases and should not be relied on for portable
>   applications.

Comment: Thank you Alon. I didnt know that! Thanks for good information!